# Hide a field from "Manage display"

Tags: 7, entities

If a field is set a hidden on *Manage display*, unless it's displayed  in a view, it cannot be seen anywhere on the site.

[Specify how fields are displayed](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/specify-how-fields-are-displayed) says:

> **Format**
> The format column contains the options to show the field value in different formats. Hidden is the global value which is present in all the format option list. If you choose hidden, it will hide the whole field from showing on the content page.

I understand it hides a field from the view mode, but you can also hide it if you don't try to do by using those modules, which are designed to output fields, like the Views module.

Is there still any possibility that users can see the hidden field even if those modules are not used?

Answer (score 0):

If you use, on *Manage display* the *hidden* format (not *label: hidden*), the field won't show for the display mode for that content type. The field could still be shown in another display mode, for example the one for teasers. You need to set the field to hidden for all the display modes.

It is still possible to make a view with the [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views) that displays the field. It depends on how you set up the view. If you set up a view of teasers, the standard teaser display is used (and the field is hidden according to the display settings). If you make a view of fields, you just have to avoid picking the "secret field."

If this is an existing Drupal site where this content type and field is a part of many different views and/or other modules, you will need to test this out. Also if the field is searchable or hard-coded in some template.